# Xcode, can't send UTF-8 Text

Tags: xcode

I am trying to send a post value to my server.

It successfully send English characters.

This code is for finding friend, and it can't send UTF-8 text.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{
/*
 Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
 */ 
if(![searchText isEqualToString:@""]){

    NSUserDefaults * userdef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *encodedSearchText = [searchText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString * uploadUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@" , GPON_URL , GPON_URL_SEARCHFRIEND];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:uploadUrl];


    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:encodedSearchText forKey:@"u_id"];
    [request setPostValue:[userdef objectForKey:KEY_USER_ID] forKey:@"s_username"];


    [request startSynchronous];
    [request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];

    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    SBJsonParser * parser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDictionary * json = (NSDictionary *)[parser objectWithString:response];


    [searchMember removeAllObjects];
    if( [[json objectForKey:@"result"] isEqual:@"YES"] ){
        [searchMember addObjectsFromArray:[json objectForKey:@"data"]];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

}

}
```

here is my code. can you see what cause the error?

Comment: whats ur problem? Do u get any errors in ur code? Please clarify!

Comment: @hp iOS Coder I said I can't send UTF-8 encoded text

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be setting the string encoding of the request; try:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setStringEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

Also, this is a very poor way of determining if an NSString is empty:

```
if (![searchText isEqualToString:@""])
```

Use the length method instead:

```
if ([searchText length] > 0)
```

Comment: [request setStringEncoding] doesn't work. where do I have to put it?

Comment: after I put your code, it says that "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'char [6]'to parameter of type 'NSStringEncoding' (aka 'unsigned int')"

Comment: You don't need to apologize to me. It still doesn't work :( Anyways Thank you!